# Sharing mutable self between multiple threads

Tags: concurrency, rust

I have a server that accepts connections from multiple clients. Each client could send a message to the server, which is broadcast to all other clients. The problem is that the function that handles each connection should have a reference to the server. However, I want to handle the connections in separate threads, so I cannot use a reference directly.

Since `scoped` is deprecated, I tried wrapping `self` in an `Arc`, but more problems ensued. Below is my attempt:

```
struct Server {
    listener: TcpListener,
    clients: Vec<TcpStream>
}

impl Server {

    fn new() -> Server {
        Server { 
            listener : TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8085").unwrap(),
            clients : vec![] 
        }
    }

    fn handle(&self) {
        println!("test");
    }

    fn start(mut self) {
        let mut handles = vec![];
        let a : Arc<Mutex<Server>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(self));
        let mut selfm = a.lock().unwrap();

        // cannot borrow as mutable... ?
        for stream in selfm.listener.incoming() {
            match stream {
                Ok(stream) => {
                    selfm.clients.push(stream);
                    let aa = a.clone();
                    handles.push(thread::spawn(move || {
                        aa.lock().unwrap().handle();
                    }));
                },
                Err(e) => { println!("{}", e); },
            }
        }
    }
```

[Rust Playground](http://is.gd/MAQjgg)

I don't understand what to do anymore, and I fear deadlocks will arise with all these locks. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: scoped was deprecated in search for a better solution. Crate crossbeam provides a new scoped thread API. Requires Rust 1.4 (soon to be released), but it's stable.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty much unrelated to having multiple threads. The issue is, as the compiler says, that `selfm` is already borrowed in the line

```
for stream in selfm.listener.incoming() {
```

so it cannot be mutably borrowed in the line

```
selfm.clients.push(stream);
```

One way to fix this is to destructure `selfm` before the loop, so the borrows don't conflict. Your `start` method will then look as follows:

```
fn start(mut self) {
    let mut handles = vec![];
    let a : Arc<Mutex<Server>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(self));
    let mut selfm = a.lock().unwrap();

     // destructure selfm here to get a reference to the listener and a mutable reference to the clients
    let Server { ref listener, ref mut clients} = *selfm;
    for stream in listener.incoming() { // listener can be used here
        match stream {
            Ok(stream) => {
                clients.push(stream); // clients can be mutated here
                let aa = a.clone();
                handles.push(thread::spawn(move || {
                    aa.lock().unwrap().handle();
                }));
            },
            Err(e) => { println!("{}", e); },
        }
    }
}
```

(That being said, you're right to be concerned about the locking, since the mutex will remain locked until `selfm` goes out of scope, i.e. only when `start` terminates, i.e. never. I would suggest an alternative design, but it's not really clear to me why you want the threads to have access to the server struct.)

Comment: I know the issue in the attached version is unrelated, but all my other attempts failed as well. The threads need access to the server, since they should tell the server to broadcast a message to all the other streams. Only the server knows the list.